# Is it possible to know when a text goes out of its block?

Tags: python, python-docx

I currently use python-docx and wanted to know if it was possible to know when a text is too long to be contained in a text frame.

The purpose of knowing this would be to reduce its size until the text fits into the frame.

If you have any other suggestions, I'm open to it.

Thanks ;)